# Print Color in image url with colorpicker value?

Tags: javascript, html, color-picker

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

    function update(){
        let src = 'https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width='+ $('#size2').val().replace('#','')+'&height=100&RenderText='+ $('#name').val().replace('#','')+'&TextSize='+ $('#size1').val().replace('#','')+'&TextColor=%23'+ $('#clr1').val().replace('#','')+'&BgColor=%23' + $('#clr2').val().replace('#','');

          $('#1Img').attr('src', src);
    }
    </script>

    Font Size: <input class="textsize" id="size1" onchange="update()"   value="55" size="3">
    Font Color: <input class="jscolor" id="clr1" onchange="update()" name="color" value="FF0000" size="6"> 
     Background Color: <input class="jscolor" onchange="update()" name="color" id="clr2" value="FFFFFF" size="6">
     Width: <input class="textsize" id="size2" onchange="update()"   value="355" size="4">
            <input class="textsize" id="name" onchange="update()"   value="[field title]" type="hidden">
     <br/>
    <img id="1Img" alt="test"  src="https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width=350&height=100&RenderText=name here&TextSize=55&TextColor=%23ff0000&BgColor=%23">

    <br/><br/>
```

Here is test mode for my code  = http://jsfiddle.net/3ugfzL68/1/

Javascript code  not update img src when I pick up color from color picker or update font or other values in input. i also interested to know if any other simple way to achieve this.
Im new to javascript or coding to please consider my request as newbie. Sorry for poor English use in my question. hope you understand my points.

Comment: It looks to me like your code works as expected. In the jsfiddle, you need to load jquery to use `$`. After including jquery in the libraries, it seems to be working.

Comment: @SamiHult im newbie so can you please update my code in jsfiddle and im also looking for other alternative for this .. thanks for time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in your code you missed jQuery.
I have added jQuery as a first library and url changing seems to work correctly.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ugfzL68/2/

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My suggestion is:
if you only want to make simple DOM manipulation you should use native js function and not include library such as jQyery. Nowedays ts not necessary to use jQuery anymore and everything can be done without it quite easily.

Also here is a code to do it withut jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function update(){
    let src = 'https://test.com/imgService.ashx?imagetype=typeit&postid=657406&width='+ document.getElementById('size2').value.replace('#','')+'&height=100&RenderText='+ document.getElementById('name').value.replace('#','')+'&TextSize='+ document.getElementById('size1').value.replace('#','')+'&TextColor=%23'+ document.getElementById('clr1').value.replace('#','')+'&BgColor=%23' + document.getElementById('clr2').value.replace('#','');        
    document.getElementById('1Img').setAttribute('src', src);
}
</script>
```

And the noJQuery fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ugfzL68/4/

Comment: thanks its work .. thanks again , im also looking for best alternatives .for this also  as i have many images on my page and i want to add these options to all images or other way is all images update with one time input put by user  .. anyways thanks

Comment: Better use noJquery code from second example if you dont need jQuery for other things. http://jsfiddle.net/3ugfzL68/4/